# Does OCI require pledging loyalty to the Indian Government?

Tags: indian-citizens, dual-citizenship, india, usa

I'm an Indian American born and raised in America.  My parents are also American citizens now, although they came from India.  Now I am considering applying for Overseas Citizen of India (OCI) status.

There's just one problem: I don't feel any allegiance or loyalty to the Indian government.  (I have lots of love for India itself, but not the current government known as the Republic of India.). So my question is, will I have to pledge loyalty to the Indian government in order to obtain OCI status?  Because I take my promises seriously, and I don't know whether I can take that such an oath in good conscience.

If such an oath is required, is there any alternate status I can obtain without such an oath?  I know that Person of Indian Origin (PIO) status was abolished recently.  But are there any other alternatives if I want to be able to do things like easily owning land and traveling to India without applying for Visas?

Answer (score 5):

No. There are no oaths required of any kind. You just have to qualify for the status and be patient with Indian bureaucracy. It can take a while.

On a side note: Make sure you get all of your details correct and have somebody proofread your application. It's a real pain to get anything updated once you've got OCI.